# Focus on first invalid text field after form validation

Tags: javascript, focus, setfocus

I have a pretty standard HTML form in which I collect user input. I have a submit button that will run a JavaScript function (onClick) that in turn validate the data entered by the users.

The function looks like this:

```
 function validateForm()
  {
    var isValid = true;

    var txtFirstname = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var txtLastname = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    (etc...)



    /*Validate First Name*/
    if(txtFirstname.length <= 0){
        document.getElementById("lblFirstName").innerHTML=" *";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("lblFirstName").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("firstName").value = txtFirstname;
    }


    /*Validate last Name*/
    if(txtLastname.length <= 0){
        document.getElementById("lblLastName").innerHTML=" *";
        isValid = false;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("lblLastName").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("lastName").value = txtLastname;
    }

    (etc...)




    if(isValid){
        document.formX.submit();
    }
    else{
        return false 
    }

  }
```

My question is: how can I set the focus on the first "invalid" textbox after the function has validated the form?

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner if you functionally decomposed your validation. Then you could have a variable called "firstInvalidField" which is initially set to null. Upon invalidation of a field, check to see if firstInvalidField is null, if it is, set it to the textBox in question. If it is not null, skip over the code.

After the validation is complete, if the firstInvalidField variable is not null, call .focus() on it.

Comment: Being very new to programming I'm unsure as to what " functionally decompose your validation" means... However I did use a variable that I check when I run through my validation and the end result works. At least for now. It seems like a lot of code so I'll see if I can clean it up a bit and make it "look better".

Comment: You'll want to refactor out the repetition into functions to minimise bug propagation.

Answer (score 2):

i search 4 it & find a better popular solution :

```
`$("#"+document.querySelectorAll(":invalid")[1].id).focus();`
```

it's work for me. note that index of first invalid input in Firefox is 1 not 0. because of in FF the form is invalid and count, when an invalid input exist.

Comment: Works, but you could just: `document.querySelectorAll( ":invalid" )[1].focus();`.
This targets the first found element and sets the focus to it, no need for the jQuery portion nor the ID attribute specification.

Comment: @Zuul Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for since I'm not using jQuery.